# The operand '+' can't be applied to operands of type string and method group

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

i have a problem in a query
my code is

```
 String reqSQL = " update Client set codClt = " + myClient._codClt 
    + ",nomClt = '" + myClient._nomClt 
    + "', prenClt =' " + myClient._prenClt 
    + " ' ,adressClt =' " + myClient._adressClt 
    + " ',numCin= " + myClient._numCin 
    + " ,datDelivCin = '" + myClient._datDelivCin
    + "' , datNaiss = '" + myClient._datNaiss 
    + "',lieuNaiss = '" + myClient._lieuNaiss 
    + "',myClient.etatCiv = '" + myClient._etatCiv 
    + "',myClient.profClt = '" + myClient._profClt 
    + "',myClient.numTelClt = '" + myClient.numTelClt 
    + "'  Where  (codClt=" + myClient._codClt + ")";
```

I get this error

```
The operand '+' can't be applied to operands of type string and method group
```

myClient is an object.

Comment: Thats a very bad way to create a sql statement

Comment: Please use [`parameterized queries`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: All the code is underlined with red line, the code is in 1 line

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the write `()` after a method name.

If I had to guess, I'd say that `myClient.numTelClt` is a method. Use it with `myClient.numTelClt()` instead.

Comment: I have not any method, i used attributes like _codClt

Comment: @TarekFellah Check again for `numTelClt`

Comment: @helb This is a guess, not an answer. You should clarify in comments before you answer without fully understanding the situation.

Comment: @RacilHilan Given a single line of code and the error message, it **must** be that the OP forgot the `()` after a method name right? The one with `numTelClt` being a method is a guess, agreed.

Comment: numTelCLt is an attribute, it should be _numTelClt

Answer (score 0):

Based on your variable naming convention you might have a typo: numTelClt might be _numTelClt.

But it would be much easier to answer you if you could show us the code for myClient's class.

Comment: This is a guess, not an answer. You should clarify in comments before you answer without fully understanding the situation.